# 'react-native run-ios' launches wrong app

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm in the process of merging an existing iOS project into react native (67.2). I've followed the guide at reactnative.dev exactly. At the moment, everything works as expected when running through Xcode. On the other hand, when I run it through npm with the command below in the terminal, the wrong app is launched on the simulator.

```
npx react-native run-ios --configuration SIBF --scheme SIBFTest
```

This is the scheme used in Xcode to build the target with a test config and a separate bundleID. But even though I specify the test scheme in the command, it still launches the release app.

I've tried a few different solutions:

- I've tried changing a lot of stuff in the build configs to try to find something that makes a difference.
- I found a pod file change which was supposed to help, but it didn't:

  project 'Sportswik',
  'Test' => :debug,
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Demo' => :release,
  'Release' => :release
- I searched for solutions but I haven't found any that works. It's a bit tricky to search on.

I'm not sure exactly why this happens, but the existing project is quite complex with multiple targets and multiple build configs. I'm new to React Native and I don't get any errors or warnings so I don't have much to go on.

If anyone has any tips, links, solutions or even scathing criticism, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, both in react-native 0.64 and 0.67.  I am unable to find any helpful resources.